# How to mock ExecutorService call using Mockito

Tags: java, multithreading, unit-testing, mockito, executorservice

I want to mock the following code snippet using Mockito.

```
Future<Optional<List<User>>> getUser =
       executorService.submit(() -> userRepository.findById(user.getUserId()));
```

I have tried with the following code, but it didn't work

```
    @Mock
    private ExecutorService executorService;

    @Mock
    private userRepository userRepository;

    when(executorService.submit(() -> userRepository.findById(USER_ID)))
           .thenReturn(ConcurrentUtils.constantFuture(userList));
```

Can anyone give me a solution for this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I have found a solution for this scenario.

We can mock executor service call using the following code snippet.

```
when(executorService.submit(any(Callable.class)))
      .thenReturn(ConcurrentUtils.constantFuture(userList()));
```

And if you have **more than one** ExecutorService calls in your method call, you can mock every response by adding them as a comma-separated list to the Mockito call as follows.

```
when(executorService.submit(any(Callable.class)))
      .thenReturn(ConcurrentUtils.constantFuture(userList()),
           ConcurrentUtils.constantFuture(Optional.of(departmentList())));
```

Answer (score 3):

You don't want to fiddle with the `ExecutorService` itself but rather mock `findById` to get the result. As long as the mock returns the result immediately (unless you let it `Thread.sleep` for a while) the call itself in the `ExecutorService` is quick and the result is hence wrapped inside the `Future`.

```
Mockito.when(userRepository.findById(Mockito.any()).thenReturn(userList);
```

Then you don't need to mock the `ExecutorService` at all, you want to use a real service, or else it doesn't do what it's supposed to do.

Comment: I have tried this, but it gave me the null value as a return value. not the userList :(

Comment: Don't mock the `ExecuteService` (remove `@Mock`), otherwise it doesn't do what it should do. (see my edit)

Comment: Thanks. When I remove the @Mock from ```ExecuteService``` I'm getting NullPointerException when invoking the ```executorService.submit``` part

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer didn't work for me because the compiler kept telling me to cast `any(Callable.class)` to a `Runnable`. So, instead I mocked it with (similar to the implementation):

```
when(executorService.submit(() -> any(Callable.class)))
      .thenReturn(ConcurrentUtils.constantFuture(userList()));
```