Testing ExecutorService with Mockito
There are smiliar questions to this but they don't quite cover the answer I need, so could anyone help a real noob to Java and Mockito? I have code as part of a larger method in a class like so:
private final ExecutorService executorService; //(also declared in constructor)


executorService.submit(() -> {
      someCool.stuffInHere
});

And I would like to unit test it with something along the lines of
@Mock
ExecutorService executorServiceMock

doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
    testSomeCoolStuffInHere;
}).when(executorServiceMock).submit(() -> any())

Is that a correct way to go about it?  I'm trying that but I keep getting an error along the lines of:
executorServiceMock.submit(CLassName$$LongLambdaAddress) at ClassName
has following stubbings with different arguments

1. executorServiceMock.submit(CLassName$$ADifferentLongLambdaAddress)

Thanks for looking.  hopefully there's enough info there.  I'm hoping it's something simple.

I would recommend not mocking an executor service at all, but perhaps using a simple direct executor, and validating the effects of the submitted logic.

I'm not sure what prevents you from deducing an answer from the very similiar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64466093/how-to-mock-executorservice-call-using-mockito

This question is similar to: How to mock ExecutorService call using Mockito. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I hope you're not trying to test the ExecutorService.

You are not submitting () -> any(). You are submitting a Callable<T> or a Runnable (the latter in your case, because you don't return a value).
So if you really want to stub the calls on the executor service (instead of using one of the existing implementations that help with testing, e.g. Runnable::run is a handy Executor to use in a test), you must use the correct argument matcher.
Your code is effectively equivalent to:
doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
    testSomeCoolStuffInHere;
}).when(executorServiceMock).submit(eq(() -> null))

Instead, you want to match a runnable:
doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {
    testSomeCoolStuffInHere;
}).when(executorServiceMock).submit(any(Runnable.class))

(or any<Runnable>() – this will match null as well)

informative and helpful.  Thankyou.

import static org. Mockito. Mockito.*;  
import static org. j unit. Assert.*;  

import org. j unit .Before;  
import org. j unit. Test;  
import org. Mockito. Mock;  
import org. Mockito. Mockito Annotations;  

import java. util. concurrent. Executor Service;  

public class Your Class Test {  

    @Mock  
    private Executor Service executor Service Mock;  

    private Your Class your Class; // Replace with your actual class that uses Executor Service  

    @Before  
    public void set Up() {  
        Mockito Annotations. in it Mocks(this);  
        your Class = new Your Class(executor Service Mock); // Inject the mock  
    }  

    @Test  
    public void test Executor Service Submit() {  
        // Arrange  
        do Answer(invocation -> {  
            Runnable = invocation .get Argument(0);  
            runnable. run(); // Execute the runnable directly  
            return null; // Return null as submit() returns a Future<?>  
        }).when(executorServiceMock).submit(any(Runnable.class));  

        // Act  
        your Class .submit To Executor(); // Call the method that uses the Executor Service  

        // Assert  
        // Verify interactions or assert conditions based on the logic within the runnable  
        // For example:  
        assert True("Your condition here", some Condition); // Replace with your actual condition  
    }  
}


Besides the formatting issues you don't explain the problem OP is having and your own code and there is excessive whitespace where the java syntax doesn't allow any.

Code-only answers without any explanation aren't really what Stack Overflow is about.  I'd expect an answer to explain what's happening, why it's happening, and how to fix it.  Also, I'd expect any code given in an answer to compile.  This doesn't.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
